# Confirm box return false won't work on server side?

Tags: asp-classic, return, confirm

I have a checking on my ASP server side, but when I have the following code. I can't get the return false to work? Can anyone kindly give me a helping hand

```
if Ubound(arr) < 0 then
        response.write "<script language='javascript'>"
        response.write "if (confirm(""Emptying the selected box will delete the Holiday Calendar Code"")==0)"
        response.write " {return false;}"
        response.write "</script>"
    end if
```

Comment: What's that intended to do?  What would it do if it did work?

Comment: I just want to prompt user a choice of continue to run the server code or stop and go back to the page. I have tried windows.history.back but the server code still continues.

Comment: There's no user on the server.  You'd have to prompt them from the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the confirm box to return false, try this:

```
if Ubound(arr) < 0 then
        response.write "<script language='javascript'>"
        response.write "if ( ! confirm(""Emptying the selected box will delete the Holiday Calendar Code"") )"
        response.write " {return false;}"
        response.write "</script>"
    end if
```

however, it will not stop any loading of the page. Server side code always executes before any client side code, so adding a confirm box will not work here as you intend it to. what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

The results:
[Still error on the return statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIvTt.jpg)

Comment: Hi Josh I have tried your method, but the return false still got errors.  Basically, what I am trying to do is I have a multiple select box. Hence during postback, if the box is empty. it will delete everything. So I want to prompt user to make a choice if they wish to continue.